# In IntelliJ, is there an action that can jump to the last viewed tab?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, pycharm

I only found "Last edited location", but usually I need to jump between two unedited files,  so that option isn't useful for me.

The Navigate -> File action is also not useful because I need to type in the name of file A and file B again and again.

In Emacs, <kbd>Ctrl+x</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> just helps me switch to the last buffer. Is there any such action in IntelliJ?

Comment: Simple ctrl-tab does the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ctrl+Alt+Left - previous position("Back" action)

Answer (score 3):

`View` | **Recent Files** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> or use the similar feature: **Switcher** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.